# How to reload webpage and stop it changing to another?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In case of high volume of transactions, when I try to enter webpage1.com, the page address will be changed into webpage2.com automatically so that only some people can reach the webpage1.com.

So I wanna ask, are there any code used to force reload only that webpage and stop it changing to another?
Thank you for answer.

Comment: I am sorry, but right now, I am not even sure exactly are you asking and what would you like to program. Or perhaps configure in which case it's probably better suited for other [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you solve such cases on the server side with load balancing.
On the client side it's harder to know if there is high load or simply network slowness. You can measure the request time and do the redirect.

This will work only for static pages or stateless apps